# java.lang.AbstractMethodError For Java 7 and Glassfish 4.0 but it Working perfectly in Java 6 with Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, java-7, hibernate-mapping, glassfish-4

I am trying to login the my application, I am getting the below error in my glassfish console.

```
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.AbstractMethodError at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:665)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy435.find(Unknown Source)
 at myservername.server.facade.__EJB31_Generated__UsersFacade__Intf____Bean__.find(Unknown Source)  at myservername.server.rest.AuthenticatorResource.getAuthenticatedUser(AuthenticatorResource.java:89)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at myservername.server.rest.ResourceAuditor.audit(ResourceAuditor.java:37) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor549.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor552.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy434.getAuthenticatedUser(Unknown Source)
 at myservername.server.rest.__EJB31_Generated__AuthenticatorResource__Intf____Bean__.getAuthenticatedUser(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
```

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish v4 is an implementation of Java EE 7, whereas v3 is of Java EE 6, so there is a big difference in APIs. The error you get results most likely from changes within those APIs, where a method is now abstract which was not at compile time of your application. So you might want to check for migration guides, such as [this](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/upgrade-guide.pdf).

And check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752997/ejb-exception-with-hibernate), which might be the same case.

Comment: As per your guidance i am using hibernate 4.3.4.final with jpa 2.1 though i am getting same error, Please Guide me if i was missing anything wrong.

Comment: It's hard to tell without your code, so you should post the part where the exception happens.

Comment: I got the Exception when calling the below facade method,                                **bold**`public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }`

Comment: Below is the Exception,                                         **bold** `Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:197) at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:341) at com.server.facade.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:33)`

Comment: If I understand it correctly, in your own code you are just calling find(...) on EntityManager, which should not cause any problem. If it happens within glassfish code, then it's beyond my ability to help. Maybe you have still things from glassfish 3 somehow bundled in your application? Or it has to do with using Hibernate, which when you google for it in combination with glassfish 4 shows some problems. Does it have to be Hibernate? Otherwise, it seems a good idea to use everything provided from Glassfish if possible.

Comment: @UbaidullaAzeem: So what was the problem and how did you solve it? Maybe it's helpful for others to mention it here.

Comment: Yes. As you said I have missed to add the latest version of libraries (hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar, hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, javaee-api-7.0.jar, jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar and jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar) to the Glassfish-4.0/glassfish/lib directory. After I added those libraries restarted the GF and It's working fine.

Comment: Also I added the below config in persistence.xml.                                  <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" /> with help of [this forum link](http://kyryloholodnov.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/hibernate-4-2-4-and-jpa-2-1/)

Comment: @UbaidullaAzeem: Although it might work, be careful about adding libs from the standard Java EE API, since they are the base of the GlassFish installation. Only add additional libs and preferably within your deployed WAR/EAR file instead of the GlassFish lib folder.

Comment: @UbaidullaAzeem: As you are new to StackOverflow, just the information that if an answer was helpful, considering voting it up and accepting it.